# GitHub giving permission denied when I try to do git push

Tags: git, github, ssh, rsa

In the past when I've done `git push origin master` from a git repo on my server, everything is fine and my latest commits are pushed to GitHub's repo.

I went to do it this morning and got this error:

```
myserver@someplace.com [~/www]# git push origin masterkey_from_blob: remaining bytes in key blob 1083
key_to_blob: unsupported key type 5
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
myserver@someplace.com [~/www]#
```

Usually github just asks me for my username and password. From some googling it seems like Key Type 5 may be som rsa_key or something? Not sure why it's trying to go this route.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should set up public keys on Github so that you don't need to enter your username/password every time. There's a tutorial on doing this here https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys

After doing this, try re-cloning your repository in a fresh directory. Patch your changes from the old repo and apply it to the new clone (or just copy+paste the modified files). Push